# What is the VBA compiler's order of events in defining classes, global variables, and subs or functions?

Tags: excel, vba, global-variables

I broke a global Enum type declaration in my code at the declaration level, leaving me thinking I missed a closing tag in a very large project with many classes and functions. Hoping to narrow my search down to whatever comes before global declarations in the compiler.
Error is "Constant Expression Required"

The enum is one of three used in a financial simulation program. I was debugging a class that I fixed and then all the enums broke. Fixing this first call with a constant just brought up an error with the next one.

I made a test sub to isolate the call, with no function calls, and still, the enum is unrecognized.

Global Declaration:

```
Public Enum DistributeType
    dSalary = 0
    dUnit = 1
    dShares = 2
End Enum

Public Enum OptionType
    oNew = 0
    oRecycle = 1
End Enum

Public Enum ColumnType
    ctName = 1      'A
    ctBirth         'B
    ctHire          'C
    ctParticipate   'D
    ctSex           'E
    ctSalary        'F
    ctHours         'G
    ctTermination   'H
    ctStatus        'I
    ctNonVested     'J
    ctCashAccount   'K
    ctLStockAccount 'L
    ctNStockAccount 'M
    ctStockDivest   'N

End Enum

Sub Test()
    Dim i As Integer

    i = DistributeType.dSalary

    Debug.Print i

End Sub
```

What I was working on:

```
Initialialize_PayOut()
With employee
    'Forfeiture Delay
        Dim i As Integer
        i = 0
        i = Range("v_DelayForf").value
        .ForfeitDelay = i

        Debug.Print "Forfeit Delay: " & .ForfeitDelay
End with
End Sub
```

Edited class Employee:

```
Private pForfeitDelay As Integer

Public Property Get ForfeitDelay() As Integer
    ForfeitDelay = pForfeitDelay
End Property

Public Property Let ForfeitDelay(value As Integer)
    pForfeitDelay = value
End Property
```

There doesn't appear to be any problems with this snippet of code, but without copying the whole project, there's no clue where it could be.

Comment: There is an ancient bug with enum parsing that can cause that error & can be  fixed by deleting one of the values, clicking out of the block then undoing or retyping it (or by simply restarting Excel)

Comment: I don't understand why that suddenly happened after 8 years of working on this project and was so easily fixed. Thank you so much. I never would have gotten there on my own.

Answer (score 0):

While not an answer to the actual question, Alex K. provided the solution to why the code was not working.

> There is an ancient bug with enum parsing that can cause that error & can be fixed by deleting one of the values, clicking out of the block then undoing or retyping it (or by simply restarting Excel) – Alex K.